# Is there any probabilistic characterization for generalized solvable groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, solvable-groups

> **References:** This question is inspired by a [conjecture](https://www.quora.com/Have-you-created-a-problem-that-you-couldnt-solve/answer/Alon-Amit) of [Alon Amit](https://mathoverflow.net/users/25/alon-amit) that is solved by Miklós Abért, Nikolay Nikolov and Dan Segal in the following papers:
>
> (1) [On the probability of satisfying a word in a group](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Eabert/research/alonveg5.pdf) (2005).
>
> (2) [A characterization of finite soluble groups](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/39/2/209) (2006).

They provided a probabilistic characterization for solvable groups as follows:

> **Theorem:** A finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if there exists some positive constant $c>0$ (depending on $G$) such that, for every $r∈\mathbb{N}$ and every $w∈F_r$ (the free group on $r$ generators), the probability that $w(g_1,\cdots, g_r)=1$ is at least $c$, where the $g_i$ are uniformly, independently chosen elements of $G$.

This characterization interestingly relates the solvability of a group to the *ease of solving equations in that group*. (See Alon's explanations in his Quora post for more intuitive descriptions).

Now consider the notion of a [hypoabelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#Hypoabelian), that is a natural generalization of the notion of solvability by allowing the sequences of derivations of a group to be of a transfinite length. (See also [Perfect Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_core)).

> **Question:** Is there any probabilistic characterization for hypoabelian groups similar to the above theorem for solvable groups? Is such a characterization related to the ordinal length of the sequence of derivations of the group? Do we need some extra set theoretic assumptions to get such a characterization for hypoabelian groups?

Comment: @Rahman.M Thank you for your effort. The question is in fact just one question regarding the formulation of Alon's conjecture for hypoabelian groups instead of solvable groups. I saw that you suggested the "finite group" tag in your previous edit. Please note that the question is non-trivial in the case of "infinite groups" so this question have nothing to do with finite groups essentially. I added the "set theory" tag because it looks to me that depending on the length of the chain one may expect some set theoretic assumptions come to the story.

Comment: I immediately changed the tag, i think it's better now.

Comment: @Rahman.M Thanks a lot. I think your edit really improved the question.